# Cancle QML DragHandlers movement

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I am using a `DragHandler` in QML to move an object around on screen. I would like to add a funtionality, that if escape is pressed while the drag is ongoing (mouse still pressed) the movement jumps back to its starting point and the drag is canceled. I am currently lost on how it accive that. The `DragHandler` does not seem to have a `cancel` or `reset` functionality. Does anyone have an idea on how to acchive this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Example code:

```js
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14

Window {
    width: 1280
    height: 768
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle

        x: 100; y: 100;
        width: 100; height: 100;

        color: "red"
    }

    DragHandler {
        target: rectangle
    }

    Shortcut {
        sequence: "Escape"
        onActivated: ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [Drag](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-drag.html#cancel-method) attached property. Despite being only showcased with MouseArea, it might work with DragHandler as well.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion? I tried multiple setups trying to attach and cancel the Drag property, but no luck so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following, we save the position when the grab is started. If an `Escape` has been received, we disconnect the `DragHandler` and restore the position. When the mouse is release, we reconnect the `DragHandler` to the target.

```
    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        x: 100; y: 100;
        width: 100; height: 100;
        color: "red"
        Text { id: txt }
        DragHandler {
            id: handler
            property bool canceled: false
            property point start
            grabPermissions: PointerHandler.ApprovesCancellation
            onGrabChanged: {
                txt.text = transition;
                switch (transition) {
                case 1: // Grab
                    handler.canceled = false;
                    start = Qt.point(parent.x, parent.y);
                    break;
                case 2: // Accept
                    handler.target = rect;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Shortcut {
        sequence: "Escape"
        enabled: handler.active
        onActivated: {
            txt.text = "Escape";
            handler.canceled = true;
            handler.target.x = handler.start.x;
            handler.target.y = handler.start.y;
            handler.target = null;
        }
    }
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Thank you very much! This already goes into the right direction! But the code you posted always makes the rectangle jump back to the "original" position (noted in the code). I would like my rectangle to jump back to the position from before the drag started. Unfortunatelly I don't see a way to acchive this using this setup.

Comment: I don't understand your requirements.

Comment: The behaviour I would like to implement is the following: The user is able to position items freely in the windows by dragging them around. Its possible to press down on an item move it around, when the user releases the mouse the item stays at the new position.

What I would like to add is the possibility to "cancel" a movement. If the user presses escape while dragging the item should jump to its "last" position from before the drag started.

Sorry if that wasn't clear!

Comment: Okay, I rewrote my answer

Comment: This works in what I was trying to acchive! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use the attached property [Drag](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-drag.html) as mentioned by me in the comment on the question, but without success.

I've managed to create a workaround by using the [`enabled`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-draghandler.html#enabled-prop) property of the `DragHandler`, but the solution has one major issue. If the escape key was pressed and the `DragHandler` was disabled the [`canceled`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-draghandler.html#canceled-signal) and [`grabChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-draghandler.html#grabChanged-signal) signals aren't triggered. Only the `grabChanged` signal is triggered when the user releases the mouse button.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        width: 100
        height: 100
        color: handler.active && handler.enabled ? "red" : "lightsteelblue"
        focus: handler.active

        DragHandler {
            id: handler

            property int x: rectangle.x
            property int y: rectangle.y

            onActiveChanged: {
                if (handler.active) {
                    handler.x = rectangle.x
                    handler.y = rectangle.y
                } else {
                    handler.enabled = true
                }
            }

            onCanceled: function(point) {
                console.log("Canceled", point)
            }
            onGrabChanged: function(transition, point) {
                console.log("Grab Changed", transition, point)
            }
        }

        Keys.onEscapePressed: {
            console.log("Pressed ESCAPE")
            rectangle.x = handler.x
            rectangle.y = handler.y
            handler.enabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the `handler.enabled` approach myself but I couldn't quite get it right since just toggling off/on wasn't enough, but, I see that you reenable it differently. Great to see you got that approach to work.

Comment: I tried something similiar, but also could not get it to work... Stephan Quans answer by reseting the target works though :) Thank you for your help!